# PHP: wrapping each group of 3 elements

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, iteration, modulus

I am trying to figure out how to write a loop that will wrap every group of 3 elements. However, for the last iteration, it should wrap whatever is left (be it one, two or three elements)

So basically this kind of pattern:

```
div
do stuff
do stuff
do stuff
end-div
div
do stuff
do stuff
do stuff
end-div
div
do stuff
do stuff
do stuff
end-div
div
do stuff
end-div
```

Here is where I'm at so far:

```
<?php

  $counter = 0;

  for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {

    if (($counter + 1) % 3 == 0) {
      echo 'div <br />';
    }
    echo 'do stuff <br />';
    if (($counter + 1) % 3 == 0) {
      echo 'end-div <br />';
    }

    $counter ++;
  }

?>
```

This is giving me the following:

```
do stuff 
do stuff 
div 
do stuff 
end-div 
do stuff 
do stuff 
div 
do stuff 
end-div 
do stuff 
do stuff 
div 
do stuff 
end-div 
do stuff
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other words, you need to write `div` before each group of three items and `end-div` after each group of three items:

```
// $counter always tells the number of processed items
$counter = 0;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    // before a group of three, $counter is a multiple of three
    if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo 'div <br />';
    }

    // process the item then count it
    echo 'do stuff <br />';
    $counter ++;

    // after a group of three, $counter is a multiple of three
    if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
        echo 'end-div <br />';
    }
}

// close the last group if it is not complete
if ($counter % 3 != 0) {
    echo 'end-div <br />';
}
```

Check it [online](https://3v4l.org/L7oZe).

Comment: I don't know why I think this one is wrong. Why in the first place check the incomplete groups outside the loop. Actually my point is, checking `$i % 3 = 0` is not enough, please because we might always have incomplete groups

Comment: It is your right to think whatever you like. You can write a better solution. Or you can check how [this code is running](https://3v4l.org/L7oZe) and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use separate `$counter` variable, make use of `$i` variable in the `for` loop itself.

```
echo 'div <br />';
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    if($i != 0 && $i % 3 == 0)
        echo 'end-div <br /> div <br />';
    echo 'do stuff <br />';
}
echo 'end-div';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem

```
$total_items = 11;



for( $i = 0; $i < $total_items; $i ++ ){
    // get the starting element
    // the starting element will have ($i + 1 ) % 3 = 1
    // all starting elements in the group will have a  modulus of 1 when divided by 3


    if( ( $i + 1 ) % 3 == 1  ){
        echo "div <br />";
    }

    echo "do stuff <br />";

    // the group will either end where ($i + 1 ) % 3 = 0
    // or at the end of the count 
    // if total items are 2 then it will end at 2

    if( ( $i + 1 ) % 3 == 0 || ( $i + 1 )  == $total_items ){
        echo "end-div <br /><br />";
    }

}
```

I ran my code using w3schools PHP compiler, please see the screenshot
[image]